# Set tick marks to RangeCrosshair in JFreeChart

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

This code

```
private JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {        
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("", "", "", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot)chart.getPlot();
    plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
    plot.setRangeCrosshairPaint(Color.BLACK);
    plot.setRangeCrosshairStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f)); 
    return chart;
}
```

results in BarChart with bold black line (f: y=0).

How to add tick marks to RangeCrosshair?
Bold black line should be like:

,-----------,------------,------------,

     A
             B
            C

Comment: You can vote this post up and I can post some image, which describes the situation more.

Comment: In the CategoryPlot class, there is a drawRangeCrosshair(...) method that you could override if you want more than just a line.  Note that the crosshair isn't fixed at y=0, normally clicking on the chart with the mouse will relocate the crosshairs (for both the x-axis (domain) and y-axis (range)).

Comment: Thanks. I have extended class MyCategoryPlot, where i override the method drawRangeCrosshair(...). How can I use the instance of MyCategoryPlot in my chart class? Is there any method like setPlot(...)?

Comment: See the source for [`ChartFactory.createBarChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.886).

Comment: Exactly as trashgod says.  There is nothing magical about the methods in the ChartFactory class, they just compose charts from the building blocks that JFreeChart provides.  Usually these methods are 5 to 10 lines that you can copy and paste into your own code if you want to modify them in some way (such as using a subclass of CategoryPlot in place of the original).

Comment: I agree. Your comments were helpful.